# Handle many ComboBox_Change Event

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

Well I'm also new in VBA programming. I'm creating a form which helps me to do quotations, and then there is a part of my form that shows items I've already registered, like this:

[My Form with ComboBoxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP6in.png)

So the purpose of those ComboBoxes is to change or delete the correponding item according with the option I choose, and I would have a lot of them in my UserForm, making it hard to create many ComboBox event programs (like ComboBox1_Change, ComboBox2_Change, ... ComboBox50_Change). And then, the main question is: how could I do it in VBA without loosing a lot of time making the same code for different objects? I would like to create just one code for all ComboBoxes.

I understand that I can do in this way below, but I'm sure that it has a better way to do.

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Call myCode
End Sub

Sub ComboBox2_Change()
  Call myCode
End Sub

Sub ComboBox50_Change()
  Call MyCode
End Sub

Sub myCode()
For i=1 to 50
   If Controls("ComboBox" & i).Value = "Change" Then
      Call MySecondCode
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I spent about 30 minutes searching about this question, but I didn't find anything good for me. I hope you guys understood my question. Thanks in advance.

Update:

Axel Richter, as I said in comments, I'm having problem in this:

```
Private Function isNOKTest()

If prod1.Value = "" Or _
    prod2.Value = "" Or _
    tecido.Value = "" Or _
    tamanhos.Value = "" Or _
    unitario.Value = "" Or _
    quantidade.Value = "" Then

        isNOKTest = True
End If

End Function


Private myCBsWithEvents As Collection
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Set myCBsWithEvents = New Collection
 For Each c In Me.Controls
  If Left(c.Name, 8) = "ComboBox" Then
   c.AddItem "CHANGE"
   c.AddItem "DELETE"
   Set myCBWithEvents = New clsCBWithEvents
   Set myCBWithEvents.myCB = c
   myCBsWithEvents.Add myCBWithEvents
  End If
 Next


End Sub

'
'
'
'datatext.Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy")
'bordadoqty.Value = 1
'estampaqty.Value = 1
'Itemlab.Caption = 1
'
```

When any code is added to the project, the event in class module doesn't work, apparently isn't linked with "Events", but I don't know what happened.

Comment: Need some more details

Comment: `Private myCBsWithEvents As Collection` is the declaration of a modul-level variable in the user form. It must be placed at the top of the user form module, in the Declarations section. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd897495%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: @AxelRichter Great, now it's working!! I'm sorry for bringing up a very simple problem, it was the first time I used class module. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using a class module which handles the events.

Insert a class module in your project. Name it `clsCBWithEvents`. In this class module have the following code:

```
Public WithEvents myCB As ComboBox

Private Sub myCB_Change()
 If Me.myCB.Value = "Change" Then
  MsgBox Me.myCB.Name & " has changed to ""Change"""
 ElseIf Me.myCB.Value = "Delete" Then
  MsgBox Me.myCB.Name & " has changed to ""Delete"""
 End If
End Sub
```

In your user form have the following code:

```
Private myCBsWithEvents As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Set myCBsWithEvents = New Collection
 For Each c In Me.Controls
  If TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
   c.AddItem "Change"
   c.AddItem "Delete"
   Set myCBWithEvents = New clsCBWithEvents
   Set myCBWithEvents.myCB = c
   myCBsWithEvents.Add myCBWithEvents
  End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Now every `ComboBox` in this user form will use this event handling.

Comment: Nice one. Not enough Class-based solutions in this forum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it works. But when I put any other command line in Userform the message box does not appear. I tried for every single Sub and Function which I have in my project, none of them is working.

Comment: When I put another function in there, the message doesn't appear. And it happens with any function not related to events (I tried even with a function that tests if every field is <> "", and the message box still not appearing).

Comment: Where do you put another function in? Please update your question. Show there the code you are using now and describe what is not working.

Comment: Check it out. When I comment that function it works. It is happening with any other sub or function I have.

Comment: `Private myCBsWithEvents As Collection` is the declaration of a modul-level variable in the user form. It must be placed at the top of the user form module, in the Declarations section. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd897495%28v=office.12%29.aspx